# Best way to train a pedestrian detector using dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, dlib

I am trying to train a pedestrian detector using [dlib](http://dlib.net/) and the the [INRIA Person Dataset](http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/).

So far I used 27 images, the training is fast but the results are unsatisfying (on other images pedestrians are rarely recognized). Here is the result of my training using the train_object_detector program that comes with dlib (in /exmaples directory) :

> Saving trained detector to object_detector.svm
>
> Testing detector on training data...
>
> Test detector (precision,recall,AP):        1 0.653061 0.653061
>
> Parameters used:
>
> threads:                 4
>
> C:                       1
>
> eps:                     0.01
>
> target-size:             6400
>
> detection window width:  47
>
> detection window height: 137
>
> upsample this many times : 0

I am aware that other images need to be added to the training in order to have better results but before doing that I want to be sure of the meaning of every parameter printed in the result (precision, recall, AP, c, eps, ...) I am also wondering if you have any recommandations regarding the training : what images to choose ? how many images are needed ? Do I need to annotate every object in the image ? Do I need to ignore some regions in the image ? ...

One last question, is there any trained detector (svm file) that I can use to compare my results ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with dlib in particular, but let me tell you that you will not get good results with 27 images. In order to generalize well, your classifier needs to see many images with a **variety** of data. It won't do you any good to supply it with 10,000 images of the same person, wearing the same outfit. You want different people, clothing, settings, angles, and lighting. The INRIA dataset should cover most of those.

Your detection window dimensions and upsample settings will determine how large people must look in the image in order for your trained classifier to detect them reliably. Your settings will detect only people at 1 scale where they are around 137/47 pixels tall/wide. If you upsample even once, you'll be able to detect people at a smaller scale (upsampling makes the person look bigger than they are). I suggest you use a larger dataset and increase the upsampling number (by how much you upsample is another discussion - that appears to be built into the library). Things will take longer, but that is the nature of training classifiers - tweak parameters, retrain, compare the results.

For precision/recall I'll refer you to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) wikipedia article. These are not parameters, but results of your classifier. You want both to be as close to 1 as possible.